# Alternative ways to install Windows 10 from USB drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-installation

It's been 4 hours now and I'm absolutely astonished by how hard it is, so I decided to seek help here.

I have a new PC on which I installed Ubuntu. I now need Windows for some work related stuff that I can't do on Ubuntu unfortunately.

I only have no CD/DVD in my PC, so I must do it from USB. Unfortunately I methods I tried so far failed, and these are:

- Copy content directly onto USB drive with exFAT partition
- Copy content directly onto USB drive with NTFS partition
- Use WoeUSB to create a bootable USB drive (I believe it also uses NTFS)

These are combined with attempts to boot both in UEFI and legacy modes. In some of them it doesn't boot at all, with WoeUSB I managed to get to prompt being shown forever.

My motherboard is Gigabyte B450M DS3H with the latest BIOS installed.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is it really that hard to install Windows?

Is there any other way I could try installing it? My resources are limited to two machines with Ubuntu and a USB drive.

@EDIT

I should have probably mentioned that I have Windows10-1909, with 4.5GB file in it, downloaded from Microsoft website. Therefore I used exFAT and not FAT32.

Comment: Normally I would suggest using a Windows computer and the [official Windows Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10). Maybe you could run that from another computer. Or maybe WINE would run it properly from Ubuntu? Either way, an EFI boot partition **must be FAT32**, not exFAT or NTFS.

Comment: @Romen I read in multiple places that exFAT should work just fine. I guess I will just have to download a different Windows version then, since I can't copy it onto FAT32.

Comment: @SamForbis unfortunately I have tried both WINE and a VM, but WINE didn't work and a VM wasn't able to deliver the kind of performance I need.

Comment: Maybe you need [this](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs) in whatever software you use to make the bootable USB as NTFS or exFAT then. Apparently [Rufus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufus_(software)) uses it. Technically EFI doesn't even specify "FAT32" in its filesystem requirements, so maybe the variant of FAT they *do* use allows for files larger than 4GB. It's not exFAT either. Also check out this official microsoft blog post about making [bootable UEFI Windows USB drives.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/archive/blogs/askcore/creating-bootable-usb-drive-for-uefi-computers).